# play apple music songs by third party applications

Tags: ios, itunes, itunes-search-api, apple-music

I am using [iTunes Search API](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/) in my application & playing the [previewUrl](http://a898.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/039/Music6/v4/13/22/67/1322678b-e40d-fb4d-8d9b-3268fe03b000/mzaf_8818596367816221008.plus.aac.p.m4a) songs from within the application by using

> AVPlayer

If user wants to play the full song, he/she needs to purchase the song from iTunes Stores only then can he/she play the full song from application.

As apple released the **[Apple Music](http://www.apple.com/in/music/)** & giving the trial OR full membership to every one & allowing to play the full songs, is it possible to play **Apple Music** full songs from my application Like **Previewurl** by using

> avplayer or mpmovieplayercontroller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@"Ted Hosmann" Thanks for reply .

I would like to share some code from [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/38878)

**viewcontroller.m**

```
@import StoreKit;

-(void) submitAppleMusicTrackWithProductID: (NSString *) productID // productID in US is the last numbers after i= in the share URL from Apple Music
{
    NSLog(@"submitAppleMusic has been called for productID: %@", productID);
    [SKCloudServiceController requestAuthorization:^(SKCloudServiceAuthorizationStatus status) {
        NSLog(@"status is %ld", (long)status);
        SKCloudServiceController *cloudServiceController;
        cloudServiceController = [[SKCloudServiceController alloc] init];
        [cloudServiceController requestCapabilitiesWithCompletionHandler:^(SKCloudServiceCapability capabilities, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            NSLog(@"%lu %@", (unsigned long)capabilities, error);

            if (capabilities >= SKCloudServiceCapabilityAddToCloudMusicLibrary)
            {
                NSLog(@"You CAN add to iCloud!");
                [[MPMediaLibrary defaultMediaLibrary] addItemWithProductID:productID completionHandler:^(NSArray<__kindof MPMediaEntity *> * _Nonnull           entities, NSError * _Nullable error)
                {
                    NSLog(@"added id%@ entities: %@ and error is %@", productID, entities, error);
                    NSArray *tracksToPlay = [NSArray arrayWithObject:productID];
                    [[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] setQueueWithStoreIDs:tracksToPlay];
                    [[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] play];

                    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(getInfoFromAddedAppleMusicTrack:) withObject:productID waitUntilDone:YES];

                }];
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Blast! The ability to add Apple Music track is not there. sigh.");
            }

        }];

    }];
}
-(void) getInfoFromAddedAppleMusicTrack: (NSString *) productID
{
    NSLog(@"FYI - musicplayer duration is: %f", [[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem] playbackDuration]);
    //need to check for both the nowPlaying item and if there is a reported playbackDuration, as there is a variable time between a storeMediaItema and a concreteMediaItem
    if (([[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem]) && ([[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem] playbackDuration]))
    {
        NSLog(@"Media item is playing: %@",[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem]);
       NSLog(@"appleProductIDURL: %@",productID);
        NSLog(@"Ending time: %d",[[[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] intValue]);
        NSLog(@"Track Name: %@", [[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]);
        NSLog(@"Artists Name: %@", [[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist]);

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"seems the track is not fully loaded so try again in 1 second");

        [self performSelector:@selector(getInfoFromAddedAppleMusicTrack:) withObject:productID afterDelay:1.0];

        // count loops and jump out if something is wrong - I've never seen more that 7 seconds needed
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the update posted for iOS 9.3 that has info about accessing the Music Library and adding Apple Music tracks...
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9_3.html